# qsort() comparing array of structs: very strange behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I am trying to sort array of structs by increase of one field (double number) but it seems that qsort() somehow corrupts data in this array (Printing array out after the call shows that fields were filled with some random values). Moreover, if I change comparator to sort array in descendant order qsort doesn't spoils data anymore but neither it sorts an array - after the call everything is the same.
This little program demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Macro for comparing floats. */
#define CMP_PREC 0.000001
#define dbl_eq(x, y) (fabs((x) - (y)) < CMP_PREC)

/* Structure for testing. */
struct level {
    double alt;
    double volume;
    double area;
};

/* Create array of levels with random alts. 
 * (Other fields are unimportant for this demo). */
struct level *create_random_arr(size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    struct level *lev = NULL;
    lev = calloc(sizeof(*lev), size);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        lev[i].alt = (double) rand() / 1000.0;
        lev[i].volume = lev[i].area = 0.0;
    }
    return lev;
}

/* Prints array in format:
 * [index]: alt=[alt], volume=[volume], area=[area]\n */
void print_levels(struct level *lev, int lev_cnt) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < lev_cnt; i++) {
        printf("%d: alt=%g, volume=%g, area=%g\n",
            i, lev[i].alt, lev[i].volume, lev[i].area);
    }
}

/* Comparator for sorting by increasing of alt. */
static int levels_compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct level *al = (const struct level *) a;
    const struct level *bl = (const struct level *) b;
    if dbl_eq(al->alt, bl->alt) {
        return 0;
    } else if (al->alt < bl->alt) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int size = 10;
    struct level *lev = NULL;
    lev = create_random_arr(size);
    /* Print generated array. */
    print_levels(lev, size);
    /* Sort array by increase. */
    qsort(lev, sizeof(*lev), size, levels_compar);
    /* Print result... very surprising, isn't it? */
    printf("----------\n");
    print_levels(lev, size);
    free(lev);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You switched the parameters in qsort, should be:

```
 qsort(lev, size , sizeof(struct level) , levels_compar);
```

I replaced `*lev` with `struct level` as i think it is better for code readability.

Comment: I disagree with your replacement. `sizeof *lev` is agnostic to the type `lev` points to, and is robust across changes in the type. Hard-coding the type will introduce serious breakage (comparable to what OP was experiencing) if the type ever changes and the compiler can't automatically diagnose it for you.

Comment: @R. With struct you get a added bonus of immediately seeing how much code you just broke( on what scope ) via compiler errors. And string find/replace is not very hard in these days. Readability>Lazyness

Comment: No you don't. With struct you get no error at all, and horrible UB at runtime. With OP's version (with the order fixed) like I'm recommending, the code automatically works.

Comment: @R.. Of course you get an error, if you code correctly. Again with laziness you get your runtime problems.

Comment: If you change the type of `lev` from `struct level *` to `struct level_ex *`, your code will still compile perfectly fine without any warnings or errors, but will break horribly at runtime (via invoking undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed up the number-of-elements and size-of-element arguments to `qsort`. This way round it works:

```
qsort(lev, size, sizeof(*lev), levels_compar);
```

As noted, you should also use `fabs` in your comparison macro. I really don't think that you need the comparison with a tolerance for sorting, however, because you're not really looking for equality but for an ascending order. I'd just go with `==` and make that the last branch, because it virtually never occurs.

Comment: You shouldn't compare floats with `==` when checking results of calculations for equality. In this case, we're not checking for equality but for sequence. The check with a tolerance can actually put values slightly out of sequence when values should have been switched in the array, because one is smaller than the other, but within the tolerance, but isn't switched becaue the two values were considered equal. To compare floats with a tolerance is good advice in general, but I think it's misguided here. (Also, this advice tends to lead to tolerances pulled out of thin air.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define dbl_eq(x, y) ((x) - (y) < CMP_PREC)
```

I do not think it is correct comparing method. Absolute values should be compared something like this way:

```
#define dbl_eq(x, y) (fabs((x) - (y)) < CMP_PREC)
```

Comment: Yeah, of course. Just made this mistake, when I was preparing code for question. I'l change the code in the question right now but the problem still exists.